# How to trick Jersey into returning embedded array?

Tags: json, jersey

I've got a Jersey-based (JAX-RS) web service that interfaces a database more than anything else it does. *Account* is an object containing, among all other sorts of obvious stuff, an embedded array of *Address* (also marked with *@XmlRootElement*):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Account
{
    ObjectId oid;
    String   name;
    String   email;
    ...
    ArrayList< Address > addresses;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Address
{
    String   street;
    String   city;
    ...
}
```

In a read operation, I obtain from the database a filled out account with addresses inside (as inspected in Eclipse). When I pass them back to my caller (see ReST service code below), all *Account* fields show up, but **not** the addresses. To make the request and see the results of this, I'm using the *Simple REST Client* extension to Chrome:

```
{
    "oid":"4fe252a73cc58a6da34eb11f",
    "name":"Yosemite Sam",
    "email":"sam@warnerbros.com"
    (but no addresses)
}
```

I expected Jersey to return something like “{ “oid”:”…”, “name”:”Yosemite Sam”, “email”:”sam@warnerbros.com”, “addresses”: [ { “street”:”17 Mariposa Way”, “city”:”Los Angeles”, ... }, { … }, { … } ] }”.

Can anyone shed some light on what (I assume) Jersey may fail to be doing here and how to trick it into doing it?

Profuse thanks,

Russ Bateman

*AccountService.java*:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
...
@POST
@Path( "/find" )
@Produces( { "application/json", "application/xml" } )
public Response read( Account account )
{
    Account result;

    try
    {
        result = accountManager.readByEmailOrOid( account );
    }
    catch( AppException e )
    {
        return e.buildResponse();
    }
    catch( RuntimeException e )
    {
        return AppException.buildRuntimeResponse( e );
    }

    return Response.ok( result ).build();  // result has addresses, but they don't show up!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, dummy me. A former colleague put me on to the solution. I needed to annotate the embedded array member with *@XmlElement*. This fixes everything.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Account
{
    ObjectId oid;
    String   name;
    String   email;
    ...
    @XmlElement          <------ don't forget this annotation!
    ArrayList< Address > addresses;
}
```

Hope this helps some other poor schmuck like me.